# WPF: Problem with taking command handlers out of code behind

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have some command binding defined in my XAML:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="commands:Commands.GrantAccessCommand"
        Executed="HelpExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

So GrantAccessCommand is located in a seperate class called Commands and HelpExecuted is in my code behind. It works fine. Now when I put HelpExecuted in the other class as well I get an error "...HelpExecuted' is not a valid event handler method name.  Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid." The code:

```
Executed="commands:Commands.HelpExecuted"
//I also tryed: Executed="x:Static commands:Commands.HelpExecuted"
```

I know I can do this in code behind using CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(GrantAccessCommand, HelpExecuted)); But I want to do this using XAML

Is there a way?

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it with this:

Define your command:

```
public class GrantAccessCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    InstalViewModel _viewModel;

    public GrantAccessCommand(InstalViewModel instalViewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = instalViewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.OnGrantAccessExecute();
    }
}
```

Create the command in the constructor of the view model

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _grantAccessCommand = new GrantAccessCommand(this);
    }
```

Expose command in your view model:

```
    public ICommand GrantAccessCommand
    {
        get { return _grantAccessCommand; }
    }
```

Bind to it in XAMl

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menuItemGrantAccess" Header="Grant Access"  
    Command="{Binding GrantAccessCommand}"
    IsEnabled=">
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is .Net 3.5. From http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CentralizingWPFCommands.aspx: The current WPF version's XAML does not allow us to bind event handlers in this way. The event handlers must be defined in the code-behind file inside the MainWindow class. I don't know if this is a bug, an accidentally left out feature, or if we are not even supposed to use this functionality, but this stops us from defining a centralized location for handling all commands' Executed and CanExecute events.

The workaround is to define bindings in code:

window.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Help, HelpExecuted, HelpCanExecute));